# Fusion Chart Multiple Charts With PHP & MySQl

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, fusion

I am generating a chart from fetching data in my MYSQL database. The JavaScript library I am using is Fusion Charts Suite XT. I have tried the following code which only renders one chart from one single query on a page. I am having trouble rendering another chart on the same HTML page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fusioncharts/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
    <?php 
include('assets/global/plugins/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.php');
include('resource/dashboard/rank_chart.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code inside the fusioncarts.php include in the page.

```
<?php

    class FusionCharts {

        private $constructorOptions = array();

        private $constructorTemplate = '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FusionCharts.ready(function () {
                new FusionCharts(__constructorOptions__);
            });
        </script>';

        private $renderTemplate = '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FusionCharts.ready(function () {
                FusionCharts("__chartId__").render();
            });
        </script>
        ';

        // constructor
        function __construct($type, $id, $width = 400, $height = 300, $renderAt, $dataFormat, $dataSource) {
            isset($type) ? $this->constructorOptions['type'] = $type : '';
            isset($id) ? $this->constructorOptions['id'] = $id : 'php-fc-'.time();
            isset($width) ? $this->constructorOptions['width'] = $width : '';
            isset($height) ? $this->constructorOptions['height'] = $height : '';
            isset($renderAt) ? $this->constructorOptions['renderAt'] = $renderAt : '';
            isset($dataFormat) ? $this->constructorOptions['dataFormat'] = $dataFormat : '';
            isset($dataSource) ? $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'] = $dataSource : '';

            $tempArray = array();
            foreach($this->constructorOptions as $key => $value) {
                if ($key === 'dataSource') {
                    $tempArray['dataSource'] = '__dataSource__';
                } else {
                    $tempArray[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

            $jsonEncodedOptions = json_encode($tempArray);

            if ($dataFormat === 'json') {
                $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/\"__dataSource__\"/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
            } elseif ($dataFormat === 'xml') { 
                $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/\"__dataSource__\"/', '\'__dataSource__\'', $jsonEncodedOptions);
                $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
            } elseif ($dataFormat === 'xmlurl') {
                $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
            } elseif ($dataFormat === 'jsonurl') {
                $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
            }
            $newChartHTML = preg_replace('/__constructorOptions__/', $jsonEncodedOptions, $this->constructorTemplate);

            echo $newChartHTML;
        }

        // render the chart created
        // It prints a script and calls the FusionCharts javascript render method of created chart
        function render() {
           $renderHTML = preg_replace('/__chartId__/', $this->constructorOptions['id'], $this->renderTemplate);
           echo $renderHTML;
        }

    }
?>
```

Inside the rank_chart.php file.

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
        // Form the SQL query that returns.
        $strQuery = "SELECT `rank_code`, COUNT(*) AS rank_cnt FROM `personel` WHERE rank_code!='' GROUP BY rank_code ORDER BY rank_code='2/LT',rank_code='LT',rank_code='CAPT',rank_code='MAJOR',rank_code='LT COL',rank_code='COL',rank_code='BRIG',rank_code='MAJ GEN',rank_code='LT GEN'";
        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result = $conn->query($strQuery);
        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result) {
            // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
            $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                   "caption"=> "",
        "xAxisname"=> "Officer Ranks",
        "yAxisName"=> "Number of Personnel",
        "plotFillAlpha"=> "80",
        "paletteColors"=> "#0075c2,#0e948c",
        "baseFontColor"=> "#333333",
        "baseFont"=> "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
        "captionFontSize"=> "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize"=> "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold"=> "0",
        "showBorder"=> "0",
        "bgColor"=> "#ffffff",
        "showShadow"=> "0",
        "canvasBgColor"=> "#ffffff",
        "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
        "divlineAlpha"=> "100",
        "divlineColor"=> "#999999",
        "divlineThickness"=> "1",
        "divLineIsDashed"=> "1",
        "divLineDashLen"=> "1",
        "divLineGapLen"=> "1",
        "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
        "showplotborder"=> "0",
        "valueFontColor"=> "#ffffff",
        "placeValuesInside"=> "1",
        "showHoverEffect"=> "1",
        "rotateValues"=> "1",
        "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
        "xAxisLineThickness"=> "1",
        "xAxisLineColor"=> "#999999",
        "showAlternateHGridColor"=> "0",
        "legendBgAlpha"=> "1",
        "legendBorderAlpha"=> "0",
        "legendShadow"=> "0",
        "legendItemFontSize"=> "10",
        "legendItemFontColor"=> "#666666"

                )
            );

            $arrData["data"] = array();

    // Push the data into the array
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["rank_code"],
                "value" => $row["rank_cnt"]
                )
            );
            }

            /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

            $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

    /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

            $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2d", "Rank Chart" , "100%", "100%", "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

            // Render the chart
            $columnChart->render();

            // Close the database connection

        }

    ?>
```